# Embed flashplayer for playing background music is not working in IE browser?

Tags: php, javascript

Hello expert i nead you help as i m faceing problem while playing background music on my web page.For this i have used this code

```
<embed src="http://www.strangecube.com/audioplay/online/audioplay.swf?file=http://localhost/ajaximage/Katy Perry - Wide Awake.mp3&auto=yes&sendstop=yes&repeat=1
&buttondir=http://www.strangecube.com/audioplay/online/alpha_buttons/classic&
bgcolor=0x507050&mode=playpause&usebgcolor=yes" bgcolor=#507050 quality=high width="30" height="30" align=""
TYPE="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"></embed>
```

From this code i used to play the background sound and also added play/pause feature to it.

It work properly for Firefox but it not working for IE browser.
So if any one know how to do it then it will very help full for me as i am having this issue from last night.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: in which version of IE the falsh is not working?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Add & Remove Programs and uninstall all the Flash entries listed. Then uninstall the Flash And after that reinstall Flash.Hope it works.